# How to make a ssl connection with a tornado server?

Tags: python, ssl, https, request, tornado

So I have a "client" which uses the python requests library to perform http/https requests with the following code:

```
proxies = {
            'http' : 'http://user:1@localhost:8888', 
            'https': 'http://user:1@localhost:8888'  
        }

r = requests.request('GET', 'https://www.instagram.com/', proxies = proxies)
```

Then this request is redirected to a tornado server. This is how I'm initializing the tornado server after using openssl to generate a certificate:

```
def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app
        , ssl_options={"certfile": "ssl/cert.pem","keyfile": "ssl/key.pem"
    })
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

So this is how my use case works: I want the communication between my client and tornado server to be encrypted, using the server certificate. Then in the tornado server I get the raw data (unencrypted) and handle the part where I send it to the url requested, in this case `https://www.instagram.com/`. Then I collect the response and send it back to the client, encrypted as well.
Is this a possible use case? Do I need additional code to handle the ssl handshake between the client and tornado server?The client can't seem to connect to the tornado server when I introduced the `ssl_options` stuff. Without it, it works fine. But I really want this use case logic to work.

Comment: you'd better put your tornado Server behind Nginx, and let Nginx handles SSL

Comment: try adding validate_cert=False on your client side, if your certificate is self signed then it works fine.